# monacaでSocket通信は可能でしょうか？

Tags: monaca

Monacaアプリで、他の機器とSocket通信をする必要があります。

そもそも、可能でしょうか？

可能であるとすれば、
組み込み可能なプラグインとかご紹介いただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

基本的にmonacaはWebViewを利用していますので、cordovaプラグインなどのネイティブベースのプラグインを利用しなくても普通に可能かと思われます。

http://socket.io

サーバにnode.jsの環境を作れない場合にはHTTPプロトコルの制約内で無理やり実現する方法もあるようです。

http://codezine.jp/article/detail/7075